# Running bash script inside VS Code with Cmder terminal

Tags: bash, shell, visual-studio-code, cmder

I've just installed VS Code and added Cmder as a default terminal on a new Win10.

I am trying to import my git for Windows `.bashrc` aliases to be used with Cmder. So I've added them to `user_aliases.cmd`.

Example alias: `make=./bin/webpack-make.sh`

If I run Cmder separately, aliases scripts run OK.  When I run them trough the VS Code terminal I get this message:

`λ dev
'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

If I add the full path I get: 
`λ dev
The system cannot execute the specified program.`

**Any Ideas why is this happening?**

btw, I've added Cmder and VSCode with Scoop.

Comment: Maybe ask in superuser.com or somewhere since your issue is not about programming.

Comment: How about using windowish path notation `make=.\bin\webpack-make.sh`?

Comment: @hradecek same :(